# HTTP and HTTPS server library for C++

Tags: c++, http

I am looking for a cross platform C++ library that can serve HTTP and HTTPS post requests. The library just need to handle the compressed file uploads through HTTP and HTTPS POST.

Answer (score 6):

How about [cpp-netlib](http://mikhailberis.github.com/cpp-netlib/)? It's coded to be a part of Boost in the future, and should be portable.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/).There are also C libraries like GNU [libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/s/libmicrohttpd/) or [Onion](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion)

Comment: Onion is AGPL, which makes it very hard to work with in most commercial situations.

Comment: No, Onion has changed license. Now it is LGPL

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at QT?

You can use it on linux, windows, ios (I think)

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qtnetwork.html

Answer (score 0):

Also for future search and reference I made an embeddable HTTP server library for C/C++ named [Libasyncd](http://wolkykim.github.io/libasyncd/), licensed with BSD, Asynchronous event-driven model, Supports HTTP/HTTPS.