# Simple HTTP Server lib

Tags: c++, http

What is a good choice for a simple http Server lib? It doesn't need high performance. I rather look for something simple for some REST/JSON communication ("API").

It must be able though to work in a multithreaded environment and must be able to handle large POST request.

Any suggestions? I already tried cpp-netlib but this seems to be much too complicated for such an easy task...

Edit: I am looking for something really light-weight and simple. E.g. like Sinatra in the Ruby world. Poco is for me another example of a too heavy-weight library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open Source C/C++ embedded web server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738273/open-source-c-c-embedded-web-server)

Comment: @MK. indeed it is, but that's a 2009 closed questions, things are likely different nowadays. Poco isn't there, for instance. There are probably /other/ questions more recent though!

Comment: maybe check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980006/http-and-https-server-library-for-c - that's really recent.

Comment: I looked into the "duplicate questions" and I don't see there anything that fits my description. (C++, very leight-weight, very simple, actual library)

Comment: Well, I think it is silly to list C++ as a requirement for a lightweight embedded web server.  What do you care if your library is C or C++ as long as it links?

Answer (score 12):

The first one that comes to mind is Poco Library ( http://pocoproject.org/ )

Cross platform, stable, well documented.  While the library itself offers more than you probably need you can build and omit the portions you aren't planning on using to reduce bloat.

They have a fully featured Net library that includes several salient classes and utilities.

Here is a pdf of slides from that library, of particular interest is the HTTPServer class:
http://pocoproject.org/slides/200-Network.pdf

Comment: Looks like a great library, but I am looking for something more light-weight.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about large POST data, but I've previously used mongoose: https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/.

If the LGPL license is unwanted there is a MIT fork from when the project was MIT that also add a C++ API https://github.com/bel2125/civetweb

Answer (score 4):

I would encourage you to start with http server samples in boost.asio. They are so simple and easy to understand, that you should be able to easily extend them as needed.

However, if you want to jump onto something more polished than just sample code, I know of 3 http servers in C++ which you may like to try:

- "x0 - HTTP Web Server Framework" to me personally this one seems most promising, because it's lightweight and simple
- "highpower / xiva" is a simple http server framework for delivering notifications to browsers
- "Pion, a project of Atomic Labs" is a part of elaborate framework for handling large amounts of data

Comment: Thanks, this boost sample code is currently my favorite solution! That code as a library and all my wishes would be fulfilled...

Comment: Quite trivial to change these samples to library code: turn `int main()` into thread function and start it in its own thread ; add to server.hpp function `"void stop() { io_service_.stop(); }` and expose it somewhere properly. However these samples are, as a I said earlier, somewhat unpolished e.g. socket shutdown in connection may lose data being sent etc.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty late answer; but hope this helps.
For your interest of a server that can handle REST, here is the easiest HTTP Server library to use (in my opinion): https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib.
For JSON parsing, you may search for another library to use it in conjunction.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd go for [Arachnida](http://arachnida.sf.net) but that might be because I wrote it.